# Why is 'Age' not considered a factor when using the 'rankabuncomp' function

Tags: r, vegan

I am trying to create Rank Abundance Curves for tree communities that are grouped according to age. I have 15 sampling sites in 8 seral stages (15(×8)) (N=120). If I had to factor my data it would look something like this:

```
Age <- factor(c(rep(1,15), rep(2,15), rep(3,15), rep(4,15), rep(5,15), rep(6,15), rep(7,15), rep(8,15)), labels =c("12","15","19","23","27","31","35","38"))
```

Now, when I use the function 'rankabuncomp' (BiodiversityR package) to create RAC curves for each seral stage, I get an error message:

> Error in diversitycomp(x, y, factor, index = "richness") : 
>     specified factor1 'Age' is not a factor
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In if ((method %in% METHOD) == F) { :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

This is the code I used:

```
Trees_2015 <- read.csv(file = "Trees_2015.csv")
Trees<- Trees_2015[,-1]
Reg_age <- read.csv(file = "Age.csv")

RAC_trees <- rankabundance(Trees,y=Reg_age, factor = "Age", level = c("12","15","19","23","27","31","35","38"))
RAC_trees
rankabunplot(RAC_trees,scale='abundance', addit=FALSE, specnames=c(1,2,3))
rankabuncomp(Trees, y=Reg_age, factor='Age', 
             scale='proportion', legend=TRUE)
```

Why is R producing this error? How can I rectify it?

The 'Reg_age' data frame (120 obvs. of 1 variable) looks something like this:

```
    Age
1   12
2   12
16  15
20  15
120 38
```

The 'Trees' data frame has 120 obs. of 75 variables (i.e. 75 different species)

Thanks
Elena

Comment: Perhaps `Age` is not a factor, but an integer. Try defining `factor = factor(Age)`.

Comment: Hi @JariOksanen I have tried factor = factor(Reg_age$Age). That produces a different error:                                                                     Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?

Comment: @JariOksanen or when I play around more I get Error in `[.data.frame`(y, , factor) : undefined columns selected

Comment: Starting from the first command, `rankabundance`-- did it fail? I think it should have failed, because you don't use it like the documentation tells you to do: the name of the `factor` must be quoted. Moreover, it seems that `level` really is singular: you can submit only one level (the function will silently accept several levels, but the results will be surprising and probably not what you assume them to be).

Comment: Apologies @JariOksanen but in the first command I did quote the 'factor'...'factor = "Age"'. It did not fail. But it is calculating RAC for the entire matrix. When I need to calculate the RAC for each seral stage (which has a total of 15 survey sites)...

Comment: That's the second point: you can only use one `level`. A vector of levels does not work like you imagine (it will work, but not in the way anybody would intend: the values are recycled for rows).